# Keep shared entries among many files

Tags: bash, perl

I have hundreds of files, each with different number of entries (>xxxx) and want to keep only shared entries among all files, separately. I'm not sure what is the best method to do this, maybe perl! I used sort, uniq of bash, but I didn't get the correct answer. The format of IDs start with > and follows 4 characters among all files.

1.fa

```
>abcd
CTGAATGCC
```

2.fa

```
>abcd
AAATGCGCG
>efgh
CGTAC
```

3.fa

```
>abcd
ATGCAATA
>efgh
TAACGTAA
>ijkl
TGCAA
```

Final results, of this example would be:

1.fa

```
>abcd
CTGAATGCC
```

2.fa

```
>abcd
AAATGCGCG
```

3.fa

```
>abcd
ATGCAATA
```

Comment: Then all files will be identical? So why not just keep a single file?

Comment: No, the entries (>xxxx) will be the same but their following line not and I need to analysis them separately.

Comment: Ok, I see the pattern now! It can definitively be done in Perl using hashes for example. But it requires a more than a one-liner. What have you tried?

Comment: How many IDs are there over all the files? Is there always exactly one line of data between the ID lines?

Comment: read about [bioperl](http://search.cpan.org/~cjfields/BioPerl-1.007001/BioPerl.pm)

Comment: @HåkonHægland I used "sort *.fa | uniq" but it mixed all in one.

Comment: @Borodin between 22-30. Yes always one line between IDs.

Comment: What should happen if `>xxxx` is in more than one file but the value beneath it differs between the files?

Comment: @PeterR: The associated data is irrelevant. The problem is to remove any ID and its data if the ID doesn't appear in all of the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Perl program will do as you ask. It uses Perl's built-in *edit in place* functionality and renames the original files to `1.fa.bak` etc. It shouldn't have a problem with blank lines in your data as long as the sequence is always on one line immediately following the ID

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @files = glob '*.fa';

printf "Processing %d file%s\n", scalar @files, @files == 1 ? "" : "s";

exit if @files < 2;

my %ids;

{
    local @ARGV = @files;

    while ( <> ) {
        ++$ids{$1} if /^>(\S+)/;
    }
}

# remove keys that aren't in all files
delete @ids{ grep { $ids{$_} < @files } keys %ids };
my $n = keys %ids;
printf "%d ID%s common to all files\n", $n, $n == 1 ? '' : "s";

exit unless $n;

{
    local @ARGV = @files;
    local $^I = '.bak';

    while ( <> ) {

        next unless /^>(\S+)/ and $ids{$1};

        print;
        print scalar <>;
    }
}
```

Comment: If there are several times the same `> abcd` in the same file, your code won't work. (not hard to correct though. And I don't know whether this could happen (should ask OP maybe); just wanted to mention it just in case)

Comment: @Dada: It's not much of a ID if it occurs twice, is it!

Comment: I tend to understand `ID` as `identifier`, and to think it's ok to use several time the same ID (unless in html/xml or such)... Is "unique" part of the meaning of "ID" ?

Comment: @Dada: Yes it is, especially in computing. An identifier *identifies* something, and if two or more things have the same name then you can't tell which one is being referred to so it doesn't work as an identifier.

Comment: @Borodin I got this error: "0 IDs common to all files". FYI there is no more than once ID in each file and all files start with ID (>xxxx) and next line text, then another ID.

Comment: @Ramon: My code works fine with your sample data. Please set up those three files, copying and pasting from your question, and try it yourself. I can't tell how your real data differs from your example. Note that you need to set the current directory to where your `*.fa` files are before you run the program. Is that the problem?

Comment: @Ramon: I've altered my program so that it tells you how many files it has found. See if that helps.

Comment: @Borodin Thank you! your code is working with the sample 3 files. Im trying to find the issue. Is sorting or order of IDs matters? Because IDs are not in the same order in files.

Comment: @Ramon: No, the order doesn't matter. Do you ever have spaces in the ID? Like `> xxxx` instead of `>xxxx`? Can you post one of the files?

Comment: @Borodin No space, and all IDs have 4 characters, then next line is data (sequences).

Comment: @Ramon: Use `Data::Dumper` and dump the `%ids` hash after the first `while` loop with `print Dumper \%ids`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Perl solution, that may help you:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file_dir = 'files';
chdir $file_dir;
my @files = <*.fa>;

my $num_files = scalar @files;
my %ids;
for my $file (@files) {
    open ( my $fh, '<', $file) or die "Could not open file '$file': $!";
    while (my $id = <$fh>) {
        chomp $id;
        chomp (my $sequence = <$fh>);
        $ids{$id}++;
    }
    close $fh;
}

for my $file (@files) {
    open ( my $fh, '<', $file) or die "Could not open file '$file': $!";
    my $new_name = $file . '.new';
    open ( my $fh_write, '>', $new_name ) or die "Could not open file '$new_name': $!";
    while (my $id = <$fh>) {
        chomp $id;
        chomp (my $sequence = <$fh>);
        if ( $ids{$id} == $num_files ) {
            say $fh_write $id;
            say $fh_write $sequence;
        }
    }
    close $fh_write;
    close $fh;
}
```

It assumes that all the `.fa` files are located in the directory named `$file_dir`, and it writes the new sequences to new files in the same directory. The new file names get the `.new` extension.

Comment: Thank you for the script. I got this error: "Use of uninitialized value $sequence in chomp at extract.pl line 27, <$fh> line 175." ANy ideas? I think $sequence hasn't defied?! or should $fh, '<', $file be $fh, '>', $file

Comment: Maybe there are empty lines in the files, or there are odd number of lines in the files? I assumed that there was always id on one line followed by sequence on next line. Test the script on the 3 sample files you provided in your question, do you still get the warning?

Comment: There is issues with files, and im fixing them.

Comment: The first `chomp (my $sequence = <$fh>)` may as well be `scalar <$fh>` as you don't use the value

Comment: @HåkonHæglandafter making all files in correct format (1st line ID then characters in the 2nd line, then another ID) still I got error: Use of uninitialized value $sequence in chomp at...

Comment: @Ramon Ok :) Let's dig into this.. Did you get the same message on the 3 sample files in your question?

Comment: @HåkonHægland your script works on the test 3 files, I given. Should the IDs need to be sorted in all files? I guess that might be issue?!

Comment: No need for any sorting as far as I can see. Could you email me your actual test files, then I can try find out what is wrong... If not, try to find a particular file where the error occurs, and email me that file alone